# Create a list counting sequential occurrences of numbers in another list

Tags: python

I have this list

```
x = [2,3,4,2,2]
```

I want to create a new list of the same size where each element will represent a count of the number of times the corresponding number has appeared in the original list before the current element. For example, the first 3 elements are 2,3,4 So, I want the first 3 values in the new list to be 0, and in `x[3]` since 2 is repeated, I want the value to be 1 and `x[4]` it's again 2 I want the value to be 2 (the number 2 has been encountered in the list twice up to this point).

My expected answer is the new list = `[0,0,0,1,2]`

Similarly for the list `[2,3,4,2,2,3,3]` I want the new list to be `[0,0,0,1,2,1,2]`

Answer (score 6):

You can leverage [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) and [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to make a simple, efficient list comprehension. By setting `count()` as the default value for your default dictionary you get a new counter item for every unique number in the list that increments as you call `next()` on it.

```
from itertools import count
from collections import defaultdict

c = defaultdict(count)
x = [2,3,4,2,2]

[next(c[n]) for n in x ]
# [0, 0, 0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can keep track of the number of times a number has been met and add it to the result accordingly.

```
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> res = []
>>> for el in x:
...     res.append(d[el])
...     d[el]+=1
... 
>>> res
[0, 0, 0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any shortcuts to solving this other than full exploration.

```
counters = {} # keep track of counts
x= [2,3,4,2,2]
new_list = [counters[c] for c in x if not counters.update({c:counters.get(c,-1)+1})]
```

Answer (score 1):

A shorter but probably less efficient solution:

```
[x[:i].count(n) for i,n in enumerate(x)]
```

Comment: Please explain why this works and what it is shorter in comparison to. I have no frame of reference since there was no code provided in the question. What are you comparing it to? What does this code do and why do you think this is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this one:

```
print([x[:i].count(x[i]) for i in range(len(x))])
```

First iterate over the index of the list: `for i in range(len)`
Then take the value at position `i` of the original list and count how many times it occurs *before* that position. For the original list `x = [2,3,4,2,2]` we obtain:

```
i=0  [].count(2) -> 0
i=1  [2].count(3) -> 0
i=2  [2,3].count(4) -> 0
i=3  [2,3,4].count(2) -> 1
i=4  [2,3,4,2].count(2) -> 2
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try this as well:

```
list = [2, 3, 4, 2, 2]
repeats = []
repeatsCounter = 0
for i in range(len(list)): #loops through the list
   for j in range(i - 1, -1, -1): #loops through every value until i
      if list[i] == list[j]:
         repeatsCounter += 1
         break
   repeats.append(repeatsCounter)
```

Comment: I am downvoting because you have not explained the solution. Please try to explain how it works and how it solves the problem.

Comment: ... and it shadows the `list` built-in, and doesn't follow PEP 8.